# Remove Padding an border around input in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

I would like to combine a checkbox and a split view (http://jsfiddle.net/rogergl/sAzbv/).

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li> <a>
            <input data-iconpos="right" name="checkbox-h-6a" id="checkbox-h-6a" type="checkbox">
                <label for="checkbox-h-6a">One</label>
            </input>
    </a>
        <a href="#" data-icon="info" onclick="alert('Hello')">
            This is a link
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So far I was not able to remove the padding/margin and the border. Is it possible to remove the padding/margin and border around the input element ?

The current working solution I have is using onclick event handler and setting an image in the event handler. But I would like to know if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of default styles with jQuery mobile that you have to override by being more specific in your CSS selectors. Example below:

```
#yourDiv a .ui-checkbox .ui-btn-icon-right .ui-btn-inner
```